# Kotlin generics issue

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, reactive-programming

The error occurs when passing `this` to `onResume`. 
Somehow it doesn't recognize that `this` implements `ActivityLifecycleType`, Am I missing something?

```kotlin
open class BaseActivity<ViewModelType: ActivityViewModel<*>>: RxAppCompatActivity(), ActivityLifecycleType {
   protected var viewModel: ViewModelType? = null

   @CallSuper
   override fun onResume() {
     super.onResume()
     viewModel?.onResume(this)  ==> Error Required Nothing, Find BaseActivity<ViewModelType>
   }
}

open class ActivityViewModel<in ViewType: ActivityLifecycleType> {
   fun onResume(view: ViewType) {
      // Do something
   }
}

interface ActivityLifecycleType {
   fun lifecycle(): Observable<ActivityEvent> 
}
```

Comment: Does `BaseActivity` extends `ViewType`? Compiler says `onResume` requires nothing, because `RxAppCompatActivity` has method `onResume` without parameters

Comment: `BaseActivity` overrides the `onResume` of `RxAppCompatActivity` my bad I edited the post but `onResume` is called on the viewmodel

Comment: You have declared `BaseActivity<ViewModelType: ActivityViewModel<*>>`: the parameter type of `ActivityViewModel` resolves to `Nothing`, thus `onResume` expects a type of `Nothing`.

Comment: try using `this@BaseActivity` instead of this.

Comment: Damn! I'm stupid it's fixed, hahaha thanks @nhaarman!

Comment: @Nodens how did u solve?

Comment: @chandil03 I replaced `BaseActivity<ViewModelType: ActivityViewModel<*>>` by `BaseActivity<ViewModelType: ActivityViewModel<ActivityLifecycleType>>`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin's generics' more strict that you have you write use the code below:

```
open class BaseActivity<ViewModelType : ActivityViewModel<ActivityLifecycleType>> : ActivityLifecycleType, RxAppCompatActivity() {
    protected var viewModel: ViewModelType? = null

    @CallSuper
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel?.onResume(this@BaseActivity)  // ==> Error Required Nothing, Find BaseActivity<ViewModelType>
    }
}

open class ActivityViewModel<in ViewType : ActivityLifecycleType> {
    fun onResume(view: ViewType) {
        // Do something
    }
}

interface ActivityLifecycleType {
    fun lifecycle(): Observable<ActivityEvent>
}
```

What I've done is to change the declaration in the first line.

Java is too weak to check the generic type but Kotlin do.

Mention there're two things you have to do next:

1. implement `lifecycle` in `BaseActivity` or make it abstract.
2. it's recommended to use `lateinit var viewModel` instead of nullable types

Comment: "it's recommended to use lateinit var viewModel instead of nullable types". No.

Comment: Well, I didn't mention that your question have already been solved :)

Comment: @ice1000 That statement was just way too broad. Use `lateinit` when it's appropriate, meaning that the variable *is* guaranteed to be initialized at some point not too far from object initialization and if it's not set to null afterwards. Use cases include Dependency Injection and variables assigned in Android lifecycle methods where you receive the `Context` for the first time.

Comment: So you mean you might get null when it's not injected. Thanks.